# Rust macro does not match passed types

Tags: macros, rust

Types passed directly to macros pattern match the way you would expect, but if they're passed through another macro as `ty`, they stop matching:

```
macro_rules! mrtype {
    ( bool )   => ("b");
    ( i32 )    => ("i");
    ( f64 )    => ("f");
    ( &str )   => ("z");
    ( $_t:ty ) => ("o");
}

macro_rules! around {
    ( $t:ty ) => (mrtype!($t));
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}{}{}", mrtype!(i32), around!(i32), around!(&str));
}
```

This prints `ioo` instead of `iiz`.

Passing `tt`s instead of `ty`s works, but if you have `&str` you need 2 `tt`s, making everything unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't work and cannot be made to work.

To summarise the [Captures and Expansion Redux chapter of The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-captures-and-expansion-redux.html): the problem is that with the exception of `tt` and `ident` captures, `macro_rules!` is completely unable to destructure or examine captured tokens.  Once you capture something as `ty`, it irrevocably becomes a black box to `macro_rules!`.

To put it another way: `&str` is not a type, as far as `macro_rules!` is concerned: it's two tokens, `&` and `str`.  When you capture and then substitute `&str` as `ty`, though, it becomes a single "meta token": the type `&str`.  The two are no longer the same, and as such don't match.

If you intend to later match against or destructure tokens, you **must** capture them as `tt`s or `ident`s (if possible).  In this *specific* case, you could rewrite the rule for `around` to instead be `($($t:tt)*) => (mrtype!($($t)*));`, which preserves the original token sequence.

Comment: `($($t:tt)*) => (mrtype!($($t)*))` worked really well for me, I just had to make sure to put in fully qualified paths in as the type arguments.